# Yii2 app debugging

Tags: debugging, error-handling, yii2

How do you debug the **yii2 app** using any IDE(eg. **eclipse, netbeans, sublime, aptana, etc...**) like debugging in **visual studio** in which we can put **breakpoints**? This is much needed, for some errors take days to fix; so any **debugging** method would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the neatbeans (and also for the other IDE) This is possibile if you have properly configurated Xdebug  and the Yii2 app if defided correctlty in a netbeans project  netbeans.

You  see https://xdebug.org/docs/install for xdebug install  or

http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Once you have installed and confiured xdebug you can run the application in (netbean) debug mode and put breakpoint ... inspecting vars .. trace .. move in the code  step by step .. with full debug functionality

Comment: I found another easy solution.,It is more easy if we are using Mamp server,the xdebug setting in mamp server is just cost one click,after that i setting up the debugger option in eclipse and debug my app easily.
By the way thanx